# Replace NULLs within a ListFields loop

Tags: arcpy, field-calculator, null, fields-attributes

I have some difficulties to change "NULL" values to zero in all "DOUBLE" fields in feature class. I have tried to make a script tool with the following Python code in ArcGIS 10.5 but it didn't work. No error messages, but nothing changes in table.

```
# Import system modules
import arcpy

# Set the parameters
InputFeatureClass = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

fieldList = arcpy.ListFields(InputFeatureClass, "DOUBLE") 
for field in fieldList:
    expression = "replaceNull(field)"
    codeblock = """def replaceNull(x):
      if x is None:
        return 0
      else:
        return x"""
    arcpy.CalculateField_management(InputFeatureClass, field, expression, "PYTHON", codeblock)
```

What is wrong? I have looked through many topics here, but couldn't find the solution.

Comment: Welcome to. GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. "Didn't work" isn't a particulary useful description of the failure. It seems wasteful to not replace ***only*** the values needed (which would be simpler, since it wouldn't need a function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Second parameter to ListField is wildcard, you want third which is field type so your list is probably empty. If you provide parameter name you dont have to worry about which position it should be and the code will be easier to read.

ListFields is listing [field objects](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/classes/field.htm) not field names. Name is one of the field object properties and you can list them like this `[f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(fc)]`

It is also easier to use the da.UpdateCursor instead of Field Calculator:

```
fieldlist = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(dataset=InputFeatureClass, field_type='Double')]

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(InputFeatureClass,fieldlist) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row = tuple([0 if v is None else v for v in row])
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: Great thanks, it works perfectly! I'm happy that you explained me cause of my error.